# Should I use a partial class for Entity Framework DBContext in another namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5

I have two projects in my solution:

Project 1: Main web project (namespace: MVCWebsite) [big]
Project 2: Daemon project (for scheduled tasks) (namespace: MVCDaemon) [small] [justcodingnow]

Project 1 has a EF DBContext, Project 2 will have EF collection (in the same context, as it uses Project 1's collections).

What is the best way to structure this?

Should I have a class in Project 2, with the same namespace as Project 1, and use a partial class of the Project 1's DBContext.

E.G, Project 1:

```
namespace MVCWebsite.Models
{
    public partial class BaseDBContext : DbContext
    {
    }
}
```

& Project 2:

```
namespace MVCWebsite.Models
{
    public partial class BaseDBContext : DbContext
    {
    }
}
```

I.E It is definitely unintinutive to have a namespace.class file in a project, whereby the normal namespace is something else!!

Is this a terrible/dangerous thing to do? Is there a better way to architect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All partial class code files must reside within the same assembly.

Hope that makes the decision easier.

The better solution is to create a 3rd project that contains the full definition of DBContext class with all the collection that is referenced from both Daemon project and web project.

Comment: Hmm at the moment, they are in a different assembly. But it seems to compile fine...